# JAVA: getMethod from a object of objects

Tags: java

i have 2 objects with "n" attribute, all this objects are declared on another Object.

Objects:

```
@Data
public class ObjectOne{
  private String  strAttribOne;
  private Integer intAttribOne;
}

@Data
public class ObjectTwo{
  private String  strAttribTwo;
  private Integer intAttribTwo;
}
```

MasterObject:

```
@Data
public class MainObject{
   private ObjectOne objOne;
   private ObjectTwo objTwo;
}
```

In another class i have an array with all my methods:

```
String[] getters = {
   "getObjOne().getStrAttribOne",
   "getObjTwo().getStrAttribTwo",
   "getObjOne().getIntAttribOne",
   "getObjTwo().getIntAttribTwo",
  }
```

now, i try to call all my methods with getMethod

```
List<MainObject> mainObjects = returnData;
int x=0;
for (int i = 0; i < mainObjects.size(); i++) {
   Method choosenMethod = MainObject.class.getMethod(getters[x]);
   System.out.println(choosenMethod.invoke(mainObjects.get(i)));
   x++
}
```

but this doesn't work, calls this error:

```
addAttachment file to request java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
com.domain.MainObject.getObjOne().getStrAttribOne()
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: *why* would you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getMethod](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) gets a method by its name, e.g. `getObjOne`. You would need two uses of `getMethod` here, one to get the `getObjOne` method and another to get the `getStrAttribOne` method.

The much easier solution is not to represent these getters as strings. You can have a list of [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) objects instead of strings, and then call their [apply](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-) method. This requires no complicated use of reflection:

```java
List<Function<MainObject, Object>> getters = Arrays.asList(
    o -> o.getObjOne().getStrAttribOne(),
    o -> o.getObjTwo().getStrAttribTwo(),
    o -> o.getObjOne().getIntAttribOne(),
    o -> o.getObjTwo().getIntAttribTwo()
);

for (int i = 0; i < mainObjects.size(); i++) {
    MainObject obj = mainObjects.get(i);
    System.out.println(getters.get(i).apply(obj));
}
```

Comment: the Function return me this error :" Cannot create a generic array of Function<MainObject,Object>"

Comment: I've changed it to a list to avoid the complications of creating a generic array, but if you need it to be an array then you can write `(Function<MainObject,Object>[]) new Function[] { ... }` and it will compile (with an unchecked cast warning).

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, the `getMethod()` accepts the name of one single method. You can't use the `.` operator inside the string. You would need to store the methods' names separatedly, an once obtained invoke them.